# How do I draw multiple coloured rectangles in HTML that print out correctly in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am generating an HTML report in my app, and I want to draw some colour preview boxes. If I use the background colour style for a div, character or table cell element, then it won't print out by default when the user prints the page from their browser (e.g. print to PDF will lose the colour box).

In Chrome and earlier versions of IE, you can manually turn on the "Print Background colour and images" option, however it is always off by default. In the Windows 10 - Edge browser, I can't seem to find this option at all, so it will surely cause support headaches for my users. Thus I'd really like to have the colours print by default without digging through options that might not be there.

Experimentation shows that the HTML5 canvas element does print by default when using fillRect(), but it requires inline javascript to draw each and every box. This massively blows out the file size as my report has a colour box in every row of a large table. There doesn't seem to be a standard way to include javascript in the CSS so that in every row I can just define the colour of the filled rectangle.

Is there a more efficient way to draw boxes in HTML that will print by default in the browser? Or do I have to inline the same javascript drawing code for every rectangle on every row?

Comment: Short answer? You probably can't. No matter how hard you try you'll always end up with a user with a particular browser version that breaks everything. And you think: ***"But the web is standardised! This should work!"*** and then realise - ***The great thing about standards is there's so many to choose from***. Welcome to web development!

Comment: Actually I'd settle for "Prints out correctly in all HTML5 compliant browsers". If I have to ditch IE9 support I will not be too upset, which probably adds SVG as an option as well.

Comment: css filters can change a color by hue, so mabey a std box can be "dyed" by just CSS. also look into box-shadow and borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of a better answer, I think the most efficient method that seems to work in most modern browsers is SVG. This code seems to work in IE9+ and all other browsers I tested, seems to print correctly regardless of background settings and is relatively compact code that doesn't require extra javascripting inline.

This code draws a purple rectangle with a thin black border. The only caveat is that it seems to be missing the left-most box outer edge in Edge (ironically), but renders fine in IE11 and Chrome, and should probably work in FF, Safari, Android and Opera.

```html
<svg width="16" height="16"> Browser does not support SVG <rect width="15" height="15" style="fill:rgb(150,150,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></svg>
```